# How to organize an OO design with two different types of users

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I've two different type of users, and I've mapped them to two Java classes **UserWheel** and **UserSea** and they have a common abstract superclass called **User**. The data saved for these user types is about the same, but the behavior is different.

Then I created an abstract class called **UserCollection** with derived classes **UserWheelCollection** and **UserSeaCollection** to search for subusers or load a subuser.

Then I've added an abstract method to UserCollection class with signature

```
public abstract List<User> listAllSubusers()
```

this is because the implementation will differ. Each User created will be a UserWheel or a UserSea, depending on which method was called, but also all the rest of the implementation is quite different.

Then I want to add a new method to UserCollection with signature **public User loadById(int idUser)**. In this case the implementation would be the same except for the fact that the User returned would be an instance of either **UserWheel** or **UserSea**. I'm reluctant in this case to use an abstract method in the base class because of code duplication.

I could check the concrete class of UserCollection with **instanceof** and create an appropriate subclass, but it doesn't seem object oriented and breaks the open-close principle.

Another idea would be to add an abstract method **createNewUser()** to UserCollection and concrete implementations in the subclasses to return a new instance, so the base class would just call this createNewUser() method.

Do you think this second path makes sense? Or you would organize things in a different way and how?

---

**UPDATE**. The current situation is:

```
abstract class User
   public String getAddress()
   public void setAddress()
   ...

class UserSea extends User
class UserWheel extends User

abstract class UserCollection
   protected abstract User createNewUser();
   public abstract List<User> listAllSubUsers();
   public User loadById(int idUser) {
       User newUser = createNewUser();
       //populate it
       return newUser;
   }

class UserSeaCollection
   protected User createNewUser() {
        return new UserSea();
   }
   public List<User> listAllSubusers()

class UserWheelCollection
   protected User createNewUser() {
       return new UserWheel();
   }
   public List<User> listAllSubusers()
```

I tried to understand the strategy pattern, as suggested by trashgod, and here is my first attempt:

```
interface SubuserManagement
    List<User> listAllSubUsers();
    ...

interface UserCrud
   void create();
   User readById(int idUser);
   void update();
   void delete();

class UserSeaCollection implements SubUserManagement, UserCrud

   private SubUserManagement subuserBehavior = new SubUserManagementSeaImplementation();
       private UserCrud userCrudBehavior = new UserCrud();

   void create {
       subUserBehavior.create();
   }
   ...

class UserWheelCollection implements SubUserManagement, UserCrud
       ...

class SubUserManagementWheelImplementation implements SubUserManagement
    List<User> listAllSubUsers();

class SubUserManagementSeaImplementation implements SubUserManagement
    List<User> listAllSubUsers();

class UserCrudImplementation implements UserCrud //only 1 implementation
   void create();
   User readById(int idUser);
   void update();
   void delete();
```

In this first attempt, I've created UserCollectionWheel and UserCollectionSea that don't share anymore a common superclass, but implement the same interfaces. The actual implementation is in external classes.

Now UserCollectionWheel and UserCollectionSea are really the same class, with the only difference of the behavior that I assign to them. Alternatively I could write just one class with setters:

```
UserCollection userColl = new UserCollection();
userColl.setSubUserBehavior(new SubUserManagementSeaImplementation());
userColl.setCrudBehavior(new UserCrud());
```

But the initialization would be cumbersome, especially if I had more behavior classes. So what am I doing wrong? How to organize this properly?

**UPDATE 2**: I wrote a [blog post](http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=795) with the design that I've implemented.

Comment: I'm not getting a sense of the outside forces that are driving this structure and what you're trying to achieve by doing this. Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to do, but avoid using programming jargon and description of specific data structures. Rather describe what these two users do, what the person using your program experiences from them.

Comment: @Hovercraft, thanks I will try, briefly. These users will do a lot of things, like creating/updating/deleting an user, creating/updating/deleting a subuser, sending different activation emails (delegating it) and so on. Since this is a stackoverflow question I tried to narrow down the scope to just two operations: list all subusers and load a single user by id. For example listing all subusers has a quite different query depending on user type, so I thought to use inheritance to map different behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of inheriting behavior, consider encapsulating it using interfaces in a [*strategy pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Users would differ in having either of two concrete implementations of an `interface ListSubUsersStrategy`, `interface CreateUserStrategy`, etc.

See also the related [*bridge pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).

Addendum: In the example below, every user has a concrete strategy for finding sub-users. In particular, `listAllSubUsers()` invokes the interface method, automatically dispatching to the right concrete implementation. The pattern doesn't relieve you of writing concrete implementations of the interface, but it does de-couple them, ensuring that changing one won't break another.

Console:

```
A has wheel users.
B has sea users.
C has wheel users.
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006323 */
public class UserMain {

    private static final List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        users.add(new User("A", new WheelStrategy()));
        users.add(new User("B", new SeaStrategy()));
        users.add(new User("C", new WheelStrategy()));
        for (User user : users) {
            user.listAllSubUsers();
        }
    }

    private static class User {

        private String name;
        private SubUsersStrategy suStrategy;

        public User(String name, SubUsersStrategy suStrategy) {
            this.name = name;
            this.suStrategy = suStrategy;
        }

        public void listAllSubUsers() {
            System.out.print(name + " manages ");
            List<User> subUsers = suStrategy.getList();
        }
    }

    private interface SubUsersStrategy {

        List<User> getList();
    }

    private static class WheelStrategy implements SubUsersStrategy {

        @Override
        public List<User> getList() {
            System.out.println("wheel users.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class SeaStrategy implements SubUsersStrategy {

        @Override
        public List<User> getList() {
            System.out.println("sea users.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I've updated the question with more details about the current situation and a temptative strategy pattern. can you take a look and see how to fix it?

Comment: I've added an example giving each user a strategy for finding sub-users.

Comment: I see, so you wouldn't use the "Collection" classes and instead you'd put everything inside User. I once read about the single responsibility principle and I thought that it should not be responsibility of the User to list themselves, look up themselves, save themselves. I also read that a way to help design is think a class like a human, an expert in a narrow field. So while the users represent themselves, they hold their data, like a passport, we could think to have an expert in listing/searching them, such as a UserManager or similar. Do you think this is not advisable?

Comment: I don't understand the problem domain well enough to say. My example was meant to suggest a way for a user to have the right behavior without `instanceof`.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, here's my take on Trashgod's Strategy pattern approach. This is not an answer, just a supporting explanation of Trashgod's answer.

```
public interface UserStore<T extends User> {
    public T create(int id);
    public List<T> listAll();
}

public class SeaUserStore implements UserStore<SeaUser> {
    public SeaUser create(int id) { return new SeaUser(id); }
    public List<SeaUser> listAll() { whatever }
}

// the dry counterpart of 'sea' is either 'land' or 'road', not 'wheel' :)
public class RoadUserStore implements UserStore<RoadUser> {
    public RoadUser create(int id) { return new RoadUser(id); }
    public List<RoadUser> listAll() { whatever }
}

public class UserCollection<T extends User> {
    private UserStore<T> store;
    public UserCollection(UserStore<T> store) {
        this.store = store;
    }
    public List<T> listAll() {
        return store.listAll();
    }
    public T getById(int id) {
        T user = store.create(id);
        // populate
        return user;
    }
}
```

This leaves it up to the client to create the UserCollection. You could wrap that; make the UserCollection constructor private, and add:

```
public class UserCollection<T extends User> {
    public static UserCollection<SeaUser> createSeaUserCollection() {
        return new UserCollection<SeaUser>(new SeaUserStore());
    }
    public static UserCollection<RoadUser> createRoadUserCollection() {
        return new UserCollection<RoadUser>(new RoadUserStore());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [genericity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). See also [Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), ch 5, item 27, _generic static factory methods_.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, now I'm studying/experimenting them. One question for now. You say "make the UserCollection constructor private, and add:" -- What is the advantage of calling **UserCollection.createSeaUserCollection()** vs **new SeaUserCollection()** -- I'm not understanding why you seem to suggest that the first way is better.

Comment: @stivlo: The advantage is that it compiles. In my example *there is no* SeaUserCollection. There doesn't need to be. You could create one, but it seems wasteful to create a whole class just to provide a constructor.

Comment: Looking at this, i'm not happy with it. The division between the collection and the store is arbitrary. It would be a bit better if `UserStore.listAll()` returned a `List<Integer>`, then the collection could still be in charge of populating the instances (delegating to the store to get the IDs and create the objects). But to be honest, i wonder if Stivlo's original inheritance approach isn't actually the best solution here.

Comment: Inheritance may be a solution, but I also suspect significant [object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

Comment: @Tom **About the private method creating the collection**: I see it now, in fact, in my tests I didn't create the two Collection classes either, but then I had to pass the strategies implementation in the constructor, which is not as easy to remember, so yes I will use that trick too. **About inheritance**: now that I've implemented your suggestions I see another problem. I was heading to create a monster class with too many methods. Using strategy keeps classes short and easy to understand.  The drawback is some added complexity. I made a few changes, I am going to review and publish them.

Comment: @trashgod: I think object-relational impedance mismatch is a wildly overstated problem. I think it's mostly a smokescreen deployed by inadequate developers who don't understand one or both of the technologies. But that's a discussion we should perhaps save for cljp.

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to a blog post (http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=795) with the design I've implemented after your answers and comments.

Comment: Now that I am learning the Spring Framework, I see that an alternative approach to having the factory methods is configure the beans in the bean configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

> I could check the concrete class of UserCollection with instanceof and create an appropriate subclass, but it doesn't seem object oriented and breaks the open-close principle.

This would break *Liskovs Substitution Principle*, which really is a rule to check that one has a sound object hierarchy. The rule says that if a method expects a `User` as an argument, it should not matter if the user is a `CompledUser`, `DirtyUser`or any other user. (Hence you may not have any `if`s checking instanceof etc).

Inheritance is all about "is-a" relationships, which basically means that you should be able to take any derived object and pass it to a method which expects the base class. If you can't do that, you are in a lot of trouble. Problems like this is because you have failed with your classes.

> Another idea would be to add an abstract method createNewUser() to UserCollection and concrete implementations in the subclasses to return a new instance, so the base class would just call this createNewUser() method

This is a a better approach, since the caller if `createNewUser` doesn't care about which kind of user it get. All it knows is that it is a user.

The approach is called factory method pattern.